# Session Expiring in ASP.net After refreshing any page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have asp.net application that was working fine till yesterday. And now if i refreshes two times and if i refresh the page third time then session is expiring and that is happening on every form

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Int32 id = 0;
        try
        {
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            MODEL.UsersCollection allUSers = new BLL.Users().Designation(Session["User"].ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i <= allUSers.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Session["Desig"] = allUSers[i].Type.ToString();
                Session["DesigID"] = allUSers[i].DesigID.ToString();
                Session["UserID"] = allUSers[i].ID.ToString();
                Session["Name"] = allUSers[i].FirstName.ToString();
                if (allUSers[i].Photo != null && allUSers[i].Photo != "")
                    Session["Photo"] = "~/User_Photos/" + allUSers[i].Photo.ToString();
                else
                    Session["Photo"] = "";
            }
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Session["Name"].ToString() + " ! " + String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", System.DateTime.Today);
            if (Session["Photo"].ToString() != "")
                ImageUser.ImageUrl = Session["Photo"].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            id = 1;
        }
        if (id == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("logout.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant code to show us? Have you checked the event viewer on the server to see if there is anything wrong with IIS? Is there some code in the application that is invalidating the session under certain conditions? More info please! =]

Comment: i have checked with event viewer there is continous event after every second and that is Login failed for user and password did not match from some random IP and i traced that IP that is unknown IP

Comment: this is the code of master page. i have used this master page on every page

Comment: Show your Web.config with the settings for SessionState

Comment: <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

Comment: <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <sessionState timeout="600">
    </sessionState>

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Constr" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=Pace!!11;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=42000;pooling='true';Max Pool Size=500;Min Pool Size=5;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBPrefix" connectionString="AGAM" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: let it go i think it was server problem. I shifted same application to new server and its working fine with the same settings.Thanks for help